# Exception in VOCE sample C++ app

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, speech-recognition, cmusphinx

I've been playing around with the C++ api of [Voce](http://voce.sourceforge.net/) for speech recognition in one of my projects. So far, I've been able to compile the C++ version of one of the sample apps provided by Voce named *recognitionTest* (provided under the samples directory in voce-0.9.1).

However, when I try running recognitionTest.exe, I hit an IndexOutOfBoundsException (console output is provided below).

```
[Voce] Java virtual machine created
[Voce] Initializing recognizer. This may take some time...
[Voce] Initialization complete
This is a speech recognition test. Speak digits from 0-9 into the microphone. Speak 'quit' to quit.
Exception in thread "Recognition thread" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 110,Size: 109
    at java.util.SubList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.SubList.get(Unknown Source)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.scorer.ScoreableJob.getFirst(ThreadedAcousticScorer.java:516)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.scorer.ThreadedAcousticScorer.scoreScoreables(ThreadedAcousticScorer.java:310)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.scorer.ThreadedAcousticScorer.calculateScores(ThreadedAcousticScorer.java:276)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.scoreTokens(SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:337)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.recognize(SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:258)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.recognize(SimpleBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:226)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.Decoder.decode(Decoder.java:94)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.recognize(Recognizer.java:116)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.recognize(Recognizer.java:135)
    at voce.SpeechRecognizer.run(SpeechRecognizer.java:129)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using Windows 8 and 32-bit version of java 1.5.

**Question**: Has someone encountered a similar error before? The exception seems to be thrown by the underlying cmusphinx library. So, I'm unable to debug the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please let me know if any additional info would be helpful in figuring out the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: voce for c++ is not a good idea. Just use cmusphinx directly http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx. It is much more accurate too.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay! I went through the wiki. However, I wasn't able to locate a sample code snippet that clearly illustrated how to use the pocketsphinx API for recognizing speech from a microphone. My application is a pretty simple one and the grammar for my application consists of just 10-15 words. 

Is there a tutorial for pocketsphinx that describes how to define a grammar file and then use pocketsphinx to convert speech to text corresponding to that grammar? (similar to this one for sphinx4 - http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialsphinx4)

Comment: Grammar specification is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/jsgf/. The code to recognize from microphone is here: https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx/blob/master/src/programs/continuous.c

Comment: Thanks for the pointers Nikolay! I've been able to build the pocketsphinx_continuous program. However, when I try running the exe, it crashes with message "pocketsphinx_continuous.exe has stopped working". One possible reason is that I'm building a 32-bit executable (Release-Win32 configuration on VS2013) and trying to run it on 64-bit machine. Is that possible? I wasn't able to build a 64-bit version. The command line I used to launch the app is "./bin/Release/pocketsphinx_continuous.exe -inmic yes -hmm model/en-us/en-us -lm model/en-us/en-us.lm.dmp -dict model/en-us/cmudict-en-us.dict"

Comment: Adding to the previous comment - when I tried building the 64-bit version of sphinxbase, it fails with the error - "Cannot open source file '..\..\src\libsphinxbase\lm\ngram_model_dmp32.c'". And since I'm unable to build sphinxbase, I'm unable to build pocketsphinx due to its dependency.

Comment: If you can not build, use prebuilt binary, they are available for download on our website.

Comment: As for error, you can just delete this file from the project.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay! Removing ngram_model_dmp32.c fixed the build issue and I'm able to run the 64-bit version. My next aim is to integrate cmusphinx API into my custom application. I have a couple of questions regarding this: (i) In my application, the user's vocabulary is restricted to 20 words only. How do I reduce the grammar size expected by cmusphinx? Is it sufficient to create a new .dict file and provide that as input? (ii) To use cmusphinx API in my app, I'm planning to use recognize_from_microphone() as a template and write a similar function in my app? Is that a correct approach?

Comment: (i) Yes, you can remove other words from the dictionary. You can do it with a text editor or with scripts. (ii) yes

Comment: Thanks Nikolay! Are there any configuration parameters that I could use to tune the accuracy of pocketsphinx? The accuracy I'm currently getting is not very satisfactory even when there's just a little noise in the environment. Apart from my custom application, I ran the pocketsphinx_continuous program and I got similar results.

Comment: To get help on accuracy you need to provide full and precise description of your decoder setup and recordings.